# Show template in loop when value matches template property

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to make a table component, which I have completed, I want to add a feature to the component where I can customize individual cells in the component. I am not exactly sure how to do this.

So I have seen this implemented like the following:

- `model` is the data related to the table (headers, rows, pagination, etc.)
- `matches` is the column name to match (in the headers id what is match, in rows it is the property key).
- `let-content` is the data associated with the cell for that row.

```html
<ui-table [model]="tableModel">
  <ng-template matches="columnA" let-content="content">
    {{content | commaSeparate}}
  </ng-template>
</ui-table>
```

```js
public tableModel = {
  headers: [
    { title: 'Column A', id: 'columnA' },
    { title: 'Column B', id: 'columnB' }
  ],
  rows: [
    { columnA: ['A', 'B'], columnB: 'Column B' },
    { columnA: ['C', 'D'], columnB: 'Column B2' }
  ]
}
```

In my `ui-table` component I have the following table body:

```html
<tbody #tBody class="uitk-c-table__body">
  <tr *ngFor="let row of rowItems" class="uitk-c-table__row">
    <!-- If "matches === model.headers[x].id" show the custom cell -->
    <td *ngFor="let cell of model.headers; index as c">{{row[model.headers[c].id] || ''}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

What I am not sure of, is how do I show the custom cell `ng-template` if `matches === model.headers[x].id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. First I create a directive which contains a `match` property which is the column I want to match on, and a `tableCell` property which is the template within the directive.

```
@Directive({ selector: 'ui-table-cell' })
export class TableCellDirective {
  @Input() public match: string = '';
  @ContentChild('tableCell', { static: false }) public tableCell!: any;
}
```

Next when the table loads I load all of the templates into an object where the key is the cell id and the value is the template.

```
export class TableComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @ContentChildren(TableCellDirective)
  public cellDirectives!: QueryList<TableCellDirective>;
  public columnMeta: { [key: string]: object; } = {};

  public ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.cellDirectives.toArray().forEach(colData => this.assignColumnMetaInfo(colData));
  }

  private assignColumnMetaInfo(colData: TableCellDirective) {
    const columnMetaInfo: { [key: string]: object; } = {};
    columnMetaInfo['tableCell'] = colData.tableCell;
    this.columnMeta[colData.match] = columnMetaInfo;
  }
}
```

In the HTML, I then check if the current cell has a template saved if so, I display the template. If not I display the original data.

```html
<tr *ngFor="let row of rowItems" class="uitk-c-table__row">
  <td *ngFor="let cell of model.headers">
    <ng-container *ngIf="columnMeta[cell.id] && columnMeta[cell.id].tableCell" [ngTemplateOutlet]="columnMeta[cell.id].tableCell" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{content: row[cell.id]}"></ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="!columnMeta[cell.id]">{{row[cell.id] || ''}}</ng-container>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Finally, to use it I just do the following:

```html
<ui-table *ngIf="tableDataModel.rows?.length>0" [model]="tableDataModel" (onRequestEdit)="onOpenEdit($event)">
  <ui-table-cell match="permissions">
    <ng-template #tableCell let-content="content">
      {{content|arrayToList}}
    </ng-template>
  </ui-table-cell>
</ui-table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your ui-table component, let's define a input property:

```
@Input() passedTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
@Input() displayContent: any // to display variable inside ng-template
```

And define a input property in order to pass your ng-template to 
Like this:

```
  <ui-table [model]="tableModel" [passedTemplate]='template' [displayContent]='content'>
  </ui-table>
   <ng-template #template matches="columnA" let-content="content">
    {{content | commaSeparate}}
  </ng-template>
```

Then try to use ng-container in your ui-table html file:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="matches === model.headers[x].id"
                          [ngTemplateOutlet]="passedTemplate"
                          [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{content: displayContent}">
</ng-container>
```

Hope this help...

Comment: Will this work if I have two cells that I want to use this template for? `<ng-template #tableCell match="abc">` and `<ng-template #tableCell match="def">` where the difference is the `match` but the `#tableCell` is the same.

Comment: Yep, you can also define a template variable, ex: let-match, and then you use *ngIf to customize content inside ng-template tag and do not forget to pass matches variable through [ngTemplateOutletContext]='{content:displayContent, match: matches}' , like this.

Comment: Instead of passing the template to the `ui-table`, I added a directive and in the `ui-table` component I added this: `@ContentChildren(TableCellDirective)
  public cellDirectives!: QueryList<TableCellDirective>;`